# Correcting misplaced cells from HTML table in R

Tags: html, r, url

I'm an R beginner and would appreciate any help! I am trying to format the extracted HTML table as a data frame. However, R places the values in some cells to different cells when reading the table, thus mixing some rows up. I'm using the basic getURL() and ReadHTMLTable () to extract the table.

For example, if the original table is like this:

```
W - X - Y - Z
A - 2 - 3 - 5
B - 4 - 5 - 9
C - 6 - 4 - 10
```

It shows up like this:

```
W - X - NA - NA
Y - Z - NA - NA
A - 2 - 3 - 5
4 - 5 - 9 - NA
C - 6 - 4 - 10
```

Specifically, I'm having this problem when trying to extract the table about [life expectancies from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy). Is there any way I could fix this (manually?..)?

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rvest package:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy"

page <- read_html(URL)
tab <- html_table(page, fill=TRUE)[[1]]
head(tab)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for a straightforward solution!

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `rvest`,

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_life_expectancy") 


first_table <- page %>% html_nodes("[class='wikitable sortable']") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)


second_table <- page %>% html_nodes("[class='sortable nowrap mw-datatable wikitable']")%>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

which returns in list format, you can use them with,

```
first_table[[1]]  
second_table[[1]]
```